# Do I need an access token for each user of my Google Analytics app?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've built a simple app that consumes the Google Analytics API.

I have authorized access through OAuth 2, but have only been using my account to save access and refresh tokens.

If I want to let others use the app, will I need to save an access token for each user?

Answer (score 0):

For web app, you just need one, and put the tracking code in every page of your app. 
I'm not sure about native app.